# C++ char array copy to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, memcpy, unsigned-char

I am trying to read a file and store the information in unsigned char arrays. However, my program seems to be overwriting variables.

ClassA header:

```
...
public:
    ClassA(void);
    void LoadMemoryBlock(char* block, int bank);
....
private:
    unsigned char upperMemoryBank1[16384];
    unsigned char upperMemoryBank2[16384];
....
```

ClassA file:

```
ClassA::ClassA(void)
{
}
...
void ClassA::LoadMemoryBlock(char* block, int bank)
{
    if (bank == 1)
    {
        memcpy(upperMemoryBank1, block, 16384);
    }
    else if (bank == 2)
    {
        memcpy(upperMemoryBank2, block, 16384);
    }
}
```

ClassB header:

```
...
private:
    ClassA* classAobject;
...
```

ClassB file:

```
ClassB::ClassB()
{
    classAobject = &ClassA();
    ...
}
...
ClassB::StoreFile(ifstream &file)
{
    int position;

    char fileData[16384];

    position = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(HEADER_SIZE, ios::beg);
    position = file.tellg();
    file.read(fileData, 16384);
    position = file.tellg();
    classAobject->LoadMemoryBlock(fileData, 1);
    classAobject->LoadMemoryBlock(fileData, 2);

    position = file.tellg(); // Crashes here
    file.seekg(16384 + HEADER_SIZE, ios::beg);
    ...
}
```

Watching the position variable in my debugger shows that after the LoadMemoryBlock calls, it no longer shows 16400 like it did beforehand, but rather a random number that is different every time. Also, the file ifstream also is corrupted by the LoadMemoryBlock call. So I am guessing that memcpy is overwriting them.

I tried initializing my arrays differently, but now memcpy crashes!

ClassA header:

```
...
public:
    ClassA(void);
    void LoadMemoryBlock(char* block, int bank);
....
private:
    unsigned char* upperMemoryBank1;
    unsigned char* upperMemoryBank2;
....
```

ClassA file:

```
ClassA::ClassA(void)
{
    upperMemoryBank1 = new unsigned char[16384];
    upperMemoryBank2 = new unsigned char[16384];
}
...
void ClassA::LoadMemoryBlock(char* block, int bank)
{
    if (bank == 1)
    {
        memcpy(upperMemoryBank1, block, 16384); // Crashes here
    }
    else if (bank == 2)
    {
        memcpy(upperMemoryBank2, block, 16384);
    }
}
```

ClassB header:

```
...
private:
    ClassA* classAobject;
...
```

ClassB file:

```
ClassB::ClassB()
{
    classAobject = &ClassA();
    ...
}
...
ClassB::StoreFile(ifstream &file)
{
    int position;

    char* fileData = new char[16384];

    position = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(HEADER_SIZE, ios::beg);
    position = file.tellg();
    file.read(fileData, 16384);
    position = file.tellg();
    classAobject->LoadMemoryBlock(fileData, 1);
    classAobject->LoadMemoryBlock(fileData, 2);

    position = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(16384 + HEADER_SIZE, ios::beg);
    ...
}
```

I thought that at least one, if not both, of these methods should work. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I have included the ClassA initialization above.

This is how I call the StoreFile method:

```
bool ClassB::Load(char* filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename, ios::in|ios::binary);

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        if(!StoreFile(file))
        {
            return false;
        }

        file.close();
        return true;
    }

    printf("Could not open file: %s\n", filename);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please try to make a full example that we can use to reproduce the problem. Otherwise we're left with mostly guessing. (You'll probably find the bug yourself while narrowing it down to such an example)

Comment: Why do you have yet another intermediate local array, rather than reading into the relevant bank directly?

Comment: Did you check that `classAobject` points to a valid object of class `ClassA` at the beginning of that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% chance the bug is in whatever code initializes the value of the `classAobject` pointer. If it points to a legitimate instance of a `ClassA` object, the code should be fine.

**Update**: Yep. That was it.

```
classAobject = &ClassA();
```

This creates a new ClassA object and then stores a pointer to it. But at the end of the statement, it goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving `classAobject` holding a pointer to a non-existing object. You want:

```
classAobject = new ClassA();
```

Don't forget the rule of three -- `delete` it in the destructor, allocate a new one on `operator=` and in the copy constructor. Or better yet, use a more C++ method like a smart pointer, depending on the semantics desired.

Comment: Consider "classAObject = new ClassA;" ... or better yet, just make it static and skip the new. If you insist on using the heap, think about boost::shared_ptr or another managed container to avoid leaking RAM.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ClassB` constructor you are initializing the `classAobject` pointer to the address of a temporary variable that becomes invalid as soon the constructor returns. This is the cause of the problem. Use `new` to create a proper heap object.